# apache commons ftp using new socket every time?

Tags: ftp-client, apache-commons-net

The Apache Commons FTPClient creates calls *openDataConnection* everytime i.e for every command it uses a separated socket.

Which means many ports are used for data transfer? Because of this sometimes i am getting into SockeReadTimeOutException which results because some Timed_Waiting ports are being used.

Not able to understand why don't a single port used for data transfer.Which consumes less memory and less stress on system. Any Advice??

Comment: Checked with windows ftp client. This also sends port command before every request. But why instead of using only one port?

Answer (score 0):

If this aspect is important to you, you may search another library. If your system allows secured file transfer (SFTP), have a look to: [JSch](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html).

I did not check the code but it might work differently compared to `FTPClient` and might not open a socket for each command.